# If offset.top is bigger than viewport height change background

Tags: jquery, background-color, offset, rgba

I'm trying to use this code to check if the Y of #site_header is bigger than viewport height.
Consider that #site_header has fixed position.
I've printed result with .html() and it seems to work correctly, but in this code sth seems wrong.
Could you help me, please?
Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var viewportHeight = jQuery( window ).height();
    var site_header_offset = jQuery('#site_header').offset();
    var site_header_offset_top = jQuery(site_header_offset.top);

    if ( jQuery(site_header_offset_top >= viewportHeight) ) {
        jQuery('#site_header').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.35)'});
    }
    if ( jQuery(site_header_offset_top < viewportHeight) ) {
        jQuery('#site_header').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0)'});
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: change `var site_header_offset_top = jQuery(site_header_offset.top);` to `var site_header_offset_top = site_header_offset.top;`

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I've modified code as you suggested me, but nth changes. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the second line, it works. (I've inverted the background color)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsct79rm/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var viewportHeight = jQuery( window ).height();
var site_header_offset = jQuery('#site_header').offset();
var site_header_offset_top = jQuery(site_header_offset.top);

if ( jQuery(site_header_offset_top >= viewportHeight) ) {
     jQuery('#site_header').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0)'});

}
if ( jQuery(site_header_offset_top < viewportHeight) ) {
    jQuery('#site_header').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.35)'});
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks Kaymaz, but it doesn't work.
Obviously if you invert backgrounds, you will see background always, but it seems not working.
I mean, if I scroll down my web page, more than the viewport height, it should change (reloading the page), but it's always the same.

Comment: I've modified your code. Check it here (it seems not working).

https://jsfiddle.net/Lsct79rm/4/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution.

```
        if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > viewportHeight ) {
            jQuery('#site_header').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.35)'});
        } else {
            jQuery('#site_header').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0)'});
        }
```

I don't understand what was wrong on my past code, but this is working. ;-)